# Is populating a model based on user input changing a good use case for Knockout?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

A user types "123" into an `input`.  On `input` change this value is passed to the datalayer which returns a model.  The model populates all the other values in the web page.  I can solve this problem with jQuery:

```
$('#mainLookup').change(function() {
    //these values come from SQL.  So I plan on sticking AJAX in here to solve this.
    //However, it would be great if knockout.js could solve these bindings for me.
    $('#data1').val('test');
    $('#data2').val('test2');

    $("#data3 option[value=2]").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

My "real" application has 22 values driven by `mainLookup`.  Can this be solved more effectively with Knockout.js?  I tried Knockout.js and got lost.  The main issue is that the framework seems to need the entire ViewModel ready to go.  In this case, I need a user input before I can obtain the rest of the ViewModel which is going to be saturated by SQL.

[Full fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/4WmSL/7/)

```
var ViewModel = function(userInput, data1Val, data2Val) {
    console.log('ko applied...');
    this.data1.val(data1Val);
    this.data2.val(data2Val);

    $("#data3 option[value=2]").attr("selected", "selected");
    console.log('ko finished');
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("This value comes from user input.", "test val", "test2 val"));
```

Here I can't apply bindings until I get user input.  So I don't know where to go with the knockout.js way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could certainly use Knockout for this. Your problem is a little vague, so it's kind of hard to figure out, but I think you are objecting to the idea that you need a value. This isn't true. You can create an empty `ko.observable` and populate it when you get the data back from your database and it *should* update automatically:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.data1 = ko.observable();
    self.data2 = ko.observable();
    self.userInput = ko.observable();
};
```

Now there are a couple of approaches to updating `data1` and `data2`, one way would be to subscribe to changes in `userInput` in your view model:

```
self.userInput.subscribe(function(newValue) { 
    $.ajax({
        // call your database and get the updated information
        // I'm using jquery here, but you can use whatever
    }).done(function(d) {
        self.data1(d.data1value);
        self.data2(d.data2value);
    });
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4WmSL/8/

If you type in the first textbox and then tab out, after 1 second (using a timeout to simulate an ajax call) the other two boxes will be populated.

If you want it to update more often (i.e. while typing rather than only when it loses focus), then see the `valueUpdate` parameter for the `value` binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

One other note, if you are trying to bind a nested property, then that can be slightly trickier. For example, say you want to bind:

```
SomeProp.SomeOtherProp
```

And `SomeProp` is an observable (`SomeOtherProp` may or may not be, it doesn't matter).

Then if you bind:

```
<div data-bind="text: SomeProp.SomeOtherProp"></div>
```

You will encounter a problem if `SomeProp` is null or undefined. In that case, you can use either the `if` or the `while` binding:

```
<div data-bind="if: SomeProp">
   <div data-bind="text: SomeProp.SomeOtherProp"></div>
</div>
```

This will stop knockout from trying (and failing) to access `SomeOtherProp` if `SomeProp` is falsy (null or undefined). Note: if you don't want to create more elements just to wrap an `if` binding, you can use virtual elements:

```
<!-- ko if: SomeProp -->
    <div data-bind="text: SomeProp.SomeOtherProp"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: A couple of things were not obvious to me as a beginner of knockout.js: 1. I can add empty observeables.  2. The existence of subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of knockout.js and the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) if you're not sure of how many fields you'll be needing to populate.

```
var mainViewModel = {
    fields: ko.mapping.fromJS(arrayDataFromServer); // [{ name: value, ... }],
    save: function() {
        // post this.fields() to your server
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then in your view, you can dynamically build a form for all of your values.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: fields">
    <li>
        <input data-bind="value: value, attr: { name: name }" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Knockout.js is a great framework for this kind of stuff!